# TimerTriggger from Monday to Friday

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cron, azure-functions

I have my timertrigger function like this, but it's not working, i want to send something from Monday to Friday at 6:00 PM

```
public static void Run(
     [TimerTrigger("0 00 18 * * * Mon,Tues,Wed,Thurs,Fri")]TimerInfo myTimer,
     ILogger log)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can know more about CRON expression with examples from this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions

Answer (score 1):

forget about it, i figured out the answer. Correct cron expression is `TimerTrigger("0 00 18 * * 1-5")` just in case someone needs it, greetings